# What options do I have to run OS X And Windows on one machine?

Tags: windows-7, macos, installation, virtualization

I want to have both Mac and Windows on one machine for my iPhone/iPad and Android application development. I want the two Operating Systems (OS) on one machine in order not to buy two different machines. I posted the question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/439313/apple-and-windows-on-one-machine) but they closed it because it was a wrong place for the post. The answer I got was to buy a Mac and dual boot (Boot Camp) OR virtualise Windows.

My question now is if I install Windows on a Mac or virtualise Windows as was suggested, can I install IDEs like Eclipse, NetBeans, etc.. on Windows in order to do my development without any limitations? I hope I'm not going to be restricted or lack any functionalities because it is a virtual Windows or through Boot Camp.  I'm only interested in installation of IDEs for my developments.

I also welcome additional ideas that I should take into consideration concerning having OS X and Windows on one machine.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. You have given me the answers i need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the license agreement](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX108.pdf), Mac OS X may only be installed on Apple hardware. In addition, OS X 10.8 can be virtualized, but only on Apple hardware as well. So buying a PC is not an option here, unless you want to build a "Hackintosh", which a) is against the license and b) might not be worth the hassle, because it simply doesn't run on all hardware combinations and you'd need to "find" your installation medium somewhere on the Internet.

That being said, you can dual-boot a Mac with OS X and Windows using [Boot Camp](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/), and nothing will stop you from doing anything you could do on a PC running Windows. Boot Camp also has drivers for Windows to recognize the Mac hardware. In essence, you can run any software on Windows as usual.

Even a virtualized Windows would offer you the same, albeit with a little less performance than a native installation. The performance drop is however hard to quantify and depends on the hardware and software you plan to run. You can buy your Mac and install Windows using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), give it a try, and if it doesn't fit you performance-wise, you might want to consider switching to a native install. Both Boot Camp and VirtualBox are also ready for Windows 8.